# Multiple copies of same process running in background, why?

Tags: command-line, process, system-monitor, top

When I run `htop`, I see multiple processes that seem to be exactly the same:

[image: htop screenshot]

What is happening? What are these processes?

Comment: It's not the same process, hence different PID (process identifier) but they all have the same parent (application) which is therefore a multi-threaded app spawning what you see.

Comment: Aha, I configured htop to show tree-view and now it make sense. thanks!